# Select subset of tensor using boolean tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have two rank-2 tensors `arr1` and `arr2` of shape `m` by `n`. The tensor `arr2` is boolean; precisely one entry in each of its rows is `True`. I want to extract a new rank-1 tensor `arr3` of length `m`, where the `i`th entry of `arr3` is equal to the entry from the `i`th row of `arr1` corresponding to where the `i`th row of `arr2` is equal to `True`.

In `numpy`, I can do this as follows:

```
arr1 = np.array([[1,2],
                 [3,4]])
arr2 = np.array([[0,1],
                 [1,0]], dtype="bool")
arr3 = arr1[arr2]
```

Can I do something similar in `tensorflow`? I know that I could `eval()` my tensors and then use `numpy` functions, but that seems inefficient.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769041/tensorflow-indexing-with-boolean-tensor) suggests the use of `tf.gather` and `tf.select`, but it does not deal with collapsing the dimensionality of the output like my question does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe use `tf.boolean_mask`?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    arr1 = tf.constant([[1,2],
                        [3,4]])
    arr2 = tf.constant([[False, True],
                        [True, False]])
    print(sess.run(tf.boolean_mask(arr1, arr2)))
```

Should give: [2, 3]