# Converting Tensor to Numpy Array - Custom Loss function In keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a custom loss function in keras. Unfortunately i have little knowledge with tensor flow. Is there a way i can convert the incoming tensors into a numpy array so i can compute my loss function?

Here is my function:

```
def getBalance(x_true, x_pred):

    x_true = np.round(x_true)
    x_pred = np.round(x_pred)

    NumberOfBars = len(x_true)
    NumberOfHours = NumberOfBars/60

    TradeIndex = np.where( x_pred[:,1] == 0 )[0]

    ##remove predictions that are not tradable
    x_true = np.delete(x_true[:,0], TradeIndex)
    x_pred = np.delete(x_pred[:,0], TradeIndex)

    CM = confusion_matrix(x_true, x_pred)

    correctPredictions = CM[0,0]+CM[1,1]
    wrongPredictions = CM[1,0]+CM[0,1]
    TotalTrades = correctPredictions+wrongPredictions
    Accuracy = (correctPredictions/TotalTrades)*100

    return Accuracy
```

If its not possible to use numpy array's what is the best way to compute that function with tensorflow? Any direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

**Edit 1:**
Here are some details of my model. I am using a LSTM network with heavy drop out. The inputs are a multi-variable multi-time step.
The outputs are a 2d array of binary digits (20000,2)

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dropout(0.4, input_shape=(train_input_data_NN.shape[1], train_input_data_NN.shape[2])))

model.add(LSTM(30, dropout=0.4, recurrent_dropout=0.4))

model.add(Dense(2))

model.compile(loss='getBalance', optimizer='adam')

history = model.fit(train_input_data_NN, outputs_NN, epochs=50,  batch_size=64, verbose=1, validation_data=(test_input_data_NN, outputs_NN_test))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT: 1 Here is an untested substitution:

(took the liberty of normalizing the variable names )

```
def get_balance(x_true, x_pred):

    x_true = K.tf.round(x_true)
    x_pred = K.tf.round(x_pred)

    # didnt see the  need for these
    # NumberOfBars = (x_true)
    # NumberOfHours = NumberOfBars/60

    trade_index = K.tf.not_equal(x_pred[:,1], 0 )

    ##remove predictions that are not tradable
    x_true_tradeable = K.tf.boolean_mask(x_true[:,0], trade_index)
    x_pred_tradeable = K.tf.boolean_mask(x_pred[:,0], trade_index)

    cm = K.tf.confusion_matrix(x_true_tradeable, x_pred_tradeable)

    correct_predictions = cm[0,0]+cm[1,1]
    wrong_predictions = cm[1,0]+cm[0,1]
    total_trades = correction_predictions + wrong_predictions
    accuracy = (correct_predictions/total_trades)*100

    return accuracy
```

#### Original Answer

Welcome to SO. As you might know we need to compute the the gradient on the loss function. We can't compute the gradient correctly on numpy arrays (they're just constants).

What is done ( in keras/theano which are the backends one uses with keras) is automatic differentiation on Tensors (e.g `tf.placeholder()`).This is not the entire story but what you should know at this point is that tf / theano gives us gradients by default on operators like `tf.max`, `tf.sum`.

What that means for you is all the operations on tensors (`y_true` and `y_pred`) should be rewritten to use tf / theano operators.

I'll comment with what I think would be rewritten and you can substitute accordingly and test.

See tf.round used as `K.tf.round` where K is the reference to the keras backend imported as 
`import keras.backend as K`

```
x_true = np.round(x_true)  
x_pred = np.round(x_pred)
```

Grab the shape of the tensor x_true. K.shape. Compute the ratio over a constant could remain as
it as Here

```
NumberOfBars = len(x_true) 
NumberOfHours = NumberOfBars/60
```

See `tf.where` used as `K.tf.where`

```
TradeIndex = np.where( x_pred[:,1] == 0 )[0]
```

You could mask the tensor w/ a condition instead of deleting - see [masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769041/tensorflow-indexing-with-boolean-tensor)

```
##remove predictions that are not tradable
x_true = np.delete(x_true[:,0], TradeIndex) 
x_pred = np.delete(x_pred[:,0], TradeIndex)
```

See `tf.confusion_matrix`

```
CM = confusion_matrix(x_true, x_pred)
```

The computation that follow are computation overs  constants and so remain essentially the same ( conditioned on
whatever changes have to made given the new API )

Hopefully I can update this answer with a valid substitution that runs. But I hope this sets on the right path.

A suggestion on coding style: I see you use  three version of variable naming in your code choose one and stick with it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! My prediction array is (20000,2) binary numbers (1's & 0's). Will  x_true,x_pred be the same format? Will the numbers be binary as well? I checked the shape of x_true it is (2,) instead.

Comment: Yes, they are the same shape and binary, without accounting for the number of examples

Comment: So i tried creating my mask like so : `TradeIndex = K.tf.where( x_pred[:,1] == 0 );   x_true = K.tf.boolean_mask(x_true[:,0], TradeIndex)` But i get an error: Shapes (?,) and (?, 0) are incompatible

Comment: see updated example that should help address the sizing issue

Comment: in the two lines below you dont need to index:                  x_true_tradeable = K.tf.boolean_mask(x_true[:,0], trade_index)
x_pred_tradeable = K.tf.boolean_mask(x_pred[:,0], trade_index)

Comment: Thanks for the update, ive tested the code and get this error `Tensor conversion requested dtype float64 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("dense_67_sample_weights:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)'`. This occurs at the compile function. I've edited my question to include the model details

Comment: Ive solved the above problem by casting to float 32 `Accuracy = K.tf.cast(Accuracy, K.tf.float32)`, However i get a new error : ValueError: None values not supported.